# Live blogging system with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, push

I want to have sort of live blogging that will allow a reporter to live blog and add updates on-the-fly.

What is the best way to do this? Check for updates every X seconds or use some kind of AJAX push?

Some examples:

> - http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-12307698
> - http://thelede.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/03/11/video-of-the-earthquake-and-tsunami-in-japan/

Comment: Not sure if it's the best way, but look into websockets. That's basically designed for streaming things to javascript on the clientside. But I don't have any experience on how well that scales up.

Comment: @Marten Veldthuis: I support that idea. Using HTML5's `WebSocket` you can have a live connection to a server, which means that as a server you can immediately send information to the client whenever you wish and the client receives it automatically. I'm using Nugget (http://nugget.codeplex.com/) as the server in my scenario, which is in C# and not too difficult to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely look at using WebSockets or some sort of push technology.

It depends on your level but you can either use a third party service like [Pusher](http://pusherapp.com/), use an open source project like [Juggernaut](http://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) or build your own.

If you're going to bake a solution yourself look at [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) and [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/). You'll also need some sort of capable pub/sub queuing system. Redis or RabbitMQ are perfect.

I feel Node.js and JavaScript are more suited to building a realtime push server but if you are more comfortable with Ruby EventMachine is also great.

I'd use Socket.IO for all solutions. Socket.IO basically uses WebSockets if your browser/mobile supports them and falls back to Flash, polling etc. It takes all the headache away involved with browsers and their lack of support for HTML5 features.

Personally I would use [Juggernaut](http://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) as that combines Socket.IO, Redis and Node.js which are the technologies I'd choose to build such a system. Juggernaut is readymade, straightforward to setup and easily scalable thanks to Node.js and Redis.